# Jquery hide show toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, show

```
$(document).ready(
        $('#p1').click(function() {
            $('#pp').toggle();
            $('#ph').hide();
        });

        $('#h2').click(function() {
            $('#ph').toggle();
            $('#pp').hide();
        });
});
```

I've gone through all of the examples here and it baffles me to why my sample isn't working because the syntax is identical. I am trying to get the element to toggle show on click and hide the other element. Any help here would be welcome. Thank you.

Here is the jsfiddle link that I am trying to get to work.
http://jsfiddle.net/88ong92f/7/

Comment: Your doc ready syntax is incorrect. Plus, the fiddle already adds a window onload wrapper so you don't need it there.

Comment: Check your console and there is a script error. Fix it and it should work.. Also I think, the second handler should be bound to `#h1`.